# Sql two multique unique ignore when first case ocours

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, unique-constraint, unique-key

My table has four columns `city`, `zipcode`, `number` and `extra`. I created unique group for `city`, `zipcode` and `number` called `unique1` and another group for `city`,`zipcode`,`number` and `extra` called `unique2`. Those groups need to be unique but the problem is that I can have non unique values when `extra` if different or is null. For example:

```
 city | zipcode | number | extra
  A      123       123      null
  A      123       123      10  (I cant add this row because of the unique groups)
```

How can I solve this problem? (I`m using Mysql)

In another words, what I need is a way to:

1) The grouping of city, zipcode and number must be unique if extra is null
2) If extra isn't null I'd like to insert that information even if the new row collides with the unique rule on '1'.

Comment: Why not _change_ `extra` instead of adding a row??  (Use `UPDATE`)

Comment: @RickJames because I need those two rows. They are diferrent when extra is diferrent or null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, using unique indexes to handle data constraints beyond simple ones is not a great idea. Other, more expensive, table servers have more elaborate ways to describe constraints.

Your first unique index (you called it a "group") -- unique1 -- prevents the second row in your example from being INSERTed to your table.

**Edit**: Your example shows that you require non-unique values for your first three columns.

I'm guessing a bit, but I think you should drop unique1 and just use unique2.

Comment: hmm the problem is that I will have non unique values for my unique1 case

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe your requirement with more details?

Comment: I edited. But it is what u said, but I cant drop unique1, beucase I need to have unique values for unique1, beucase if I drop it, I will have city, zipcode and number equals , right?

Comment: delete record 2, drop unique1, then add record2 back

Answer (score 0):

Drop unique1, unique2 should take care of it.